# A WYSIWYG editor for only bold italic and list

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on a cross browser WYSIWYG editor for producing only lsits, bold and italic. I don't want to use markdown because my users are not very computer friendly, and I also don't need them to have many controls.

My experience of WYSIWYG editors is that they are huge sledgehammers and I only want to crack open a small nut.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can customize `Wysiwyg` editors to your requirements

Comment: I guess that every WYSIWYG editor can be configured to produce only bold, italic and list. Question is - which can also filter input (pasting, d&d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 11/11/2015:

The Wysihtml editor mentioned below now lives here: https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml

And since I mentioned Basecamp, they have a new rich text editor (written for Basecamp 3): https://github.com/basecamp/trix

Trix targets modern browsers (IE11+), so if you need older IE support, Wysihtml may still be a better choice.

---

### OLD 7/11/2013:

This seems to be a reasonably modern one: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

I believe it's used on Basecamp.

Supported in IE8+, FF 3.5+, Safari 4+, Safari on iOS 5+, Opera 11+ and Chrome.

[Simple Demo](http://web.archive.org/web/20130129093818/https://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/examples/simple.html)

[Advanced Demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128154101/https://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/examples/advanced.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [line-control](http://suyati.github.io/line-control/).You can also find the demo in `github`

Answer (score 2):

Froala editor http://editor.froala.com is a very good choice. You can customize what buttons to use.

Works on all major browsers and on mobile too.

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest editor ive found : http://nicedit.com/demos.php

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE can do this but you have to configure it.

go to http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/custom_toolbar_button.php and click the "View Source" tab

change this line:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "mybutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
```

into:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,bullist,numlist",
```

Answer (score -1):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php) allows to configure which options are available to format text. It's open source under LGPL

```
toolbar: "bold italic |"
```